# Google/Facebook OAuth for dev/production

Tags: facebook, oauth, google-oauth, development-environment, production-environment

when using OAuth from Google, you have to create project in Developer console and then create Oauth credentials. You will get client secret, client ID... Should I create 2 projects? One with credentials for production environment and second for DEV enviroment? How should I handle this?

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks!